# Sink component doesn't get the right data with kafka in spring cloud data flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-dataflow, spring-kafka

I am not a native English speaker but I try to express my question as clear as possible.
I encountered this problem which has confused me for two days and I still can't find the solution.

I have built a stream which will run in the Spring Could Data Flow in the Hadoop YARN.

The stream is composed of Http source,processor and file sink.

**1.Http Source**
The HTTP Source component has two output channels binding with two different destinations which are dest1 and dest2 defined in the application.properties.

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=dest1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output2.destination=dest2

Below is the code snipet for HTTP source for your reference..

```
@Autowired
    private EssSource channels; //EssSource is the interface for multiple output channels

##output channel 1:
    @RequestMapping(path = "/file", method = POST, consumes = {"text/*", "application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void handleRequest(@RequestBody byte[] body, @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE) Object contentType) {
        logger.info("enter ... handleRequest1...");
        channels.output().send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(body,
                new MessageHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType))));
    }

##output channel 2:
    @RequestMapping(path = "/test", method = POST, consumes = {"text/*", "application/json"})
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.ACCEPTED)
    public void handleRequest2(@RequestBody byte[] body, @RequestHeader(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE) Object contentType) {
        logger.info("enter ... handleRequest2...");
        channels.output2().send(MessageBuilder.createMessage(body,
                new MessageHeaders(Collections.singletonMap(MessageHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, contentType))));
    }
```

**2. Processor**
The processor has two multiple input channels and two output channels binding with different destinations.
   The destination binding is defined in application.properties in processor component project.

```
//input channel binding  
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=dest1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input2.destination=dest2

//output channel binding  
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=hdfsSink
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output2.destination=fileSink
```

Below is the code snippet for Processor.

```
@Transformer(inputChannel = EssProcessor.INPUT, outputChannel = EssProcessor.OUTPUT)
    public Object transform(Message<?> message) {
        logger.info("enter ...transform...");

        return "processed by transform1";;
    }


    @Transformer(inputChannel = EssProcessor.INPUT_2, outputChannel = EssProcessor.OUTPUT_2)
    public Object transform2(Message<?> message) {
        logger.info("enter ... transform2...");
        return "processed by transform2";
    }
```

**3. The file sink component.**

I use the official fil sink component from Spring. 
   maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:file-sink-kafka:1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT

And I just add the destination binding in its applicaiton.properties file.
   spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=fileSink

**4.Finding:**

The data flow I expected should like this:

Source.handleRequest() -->Processor.handleRequest()

Source.handleRequest2() -->Processor.handleRequest2() --> Sink.fileWritingMessageHandler();

Should only the string "processed by transform2" is saved to the file.

But after my testing, the data flow is actual like this:

Source.handleRequest() -->Processor.handleRequest() --> Sink.fileWritingMessageHandler();

Source.handleRequest2() -->Processor.handleRequest2() --> Sink.fileWritingMessageHandler();

Both the "processed by transform1" and "processed by transform2" string are saved to the file.

**5.Question:**

Although the destination for the output channel in Processor.handleRequest() binds to hdfsSink instead of fileSink,the data still flows to file Sink. I can't understand this and this is not what I want.
  I only want the data from Processor.handleRequest2() flows to file sink instead of both.
  If I don't do it right, could anyone tell me how to do it and what is the solution?
  It has been confused me for 2 days.

Thanks you for your kindly help.

Alex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is your stream definition something like this (where the '-2' versions are the ones with multiple channels) ?

```
http-source-2 | processor-2 | file-sink
```

Note that Spring Cloud Data Flow will override the destinations defined in `applications.properties` which is why, even if `spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination` for the processor is set to `hdfs-sink`, it will actually match the input of `file-sink`.

The way destinations are configured from a stream definition is explained here (in the context of taps): http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#spring-cloud-dataflow-stream-tap-dsl

What you can do is to simply swap the meaning of channel 1 and 2 - use the side channel for hdfs. This is a bit brittle though - as the `input`/`output` channels of the Stream will be configured automatically and the other channels will be configured via `application.properties` - in this case it may be better to configure the side channel destinations via stream definition or at deployment time - see http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_application_properties.

It seems to me that these could be just as well be 2 streams listening to separate endpoints, using regular components - given that data is supposed to be flowing side by side.

Comment: Hi Marius,  

Thanks for the answer. It works now.
Thank you so much. It really helps.

Comment: By the way, when I did the testing on YARN this afternoon, I found that it seems the SCDF on YARN not only caches the Apps in the /dataflow/artifacts/cache folder, but also elsewhere like database.
I am not sure if it also caches the apps in DB.
As even I destroy the stream and unregister the Apps and delete all the files in /dataflow/artifacts/cache folder, I found that the SCDF on Yarn still use the cached Apps to deploy.
At last, I have no choice but restart the SCDF Server and it works.
Do you know how to clear the cache data completely without restart the Server?

Thanks,

Comment: This [section in the docs](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow-server-yarn/docs/1.0.1.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#yarn-how-it-works) could be useful. Caching is done at `/dataflow/artifacts/cache` and as well as in the `hdfs` directory, so whenever you clear the cache, you may have to restart the server, too. Please feel free to share your feedback and/or improvements to this workflow.

Comment: Thanks Sabby for the feedback.
Except the /dataflow/artifacts/cache directory where Caching is done, do you know where is the hdfs directory? I don't want to restart the server to clear the cache because if we do, all the streams have to be re-deployed manually again even we only update one app in one stream.

Comment: Have you tried registering that "one app" with `--force` option? This should override the existing and the latest would be used. Also, the original topic on this thread is already addressed and this is a different discussion altogether - perhaps you could consider closing this and open a new thread if you're still having issues with it.

Comment: Ok, I will try it and if needed, I will open a new thread for it.
I will close this thread. Thanks Sabby.